# How Do I Format Date in Model or Linq Query for Controller Output

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an API controller that renders a JSON result which is used by the infinite scroll plugin. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to format the output using the plugin itself, so I have to make sure the output is properly formatted before it is sent to the controller.

I have run into a problem with DateTime because all the examples I can find for formatting it rely on using server side code in the view. That is not an option with infinite scroll.

Preferably this should be done in the LINQ query or the model. I tried changing my model to:

```
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? Date
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

That did not work. Likewise, changing the part of the select clause of the link query that says Date = p.Date to stuff like Convert.ToDateTime(p.Date).ToString("dddd MMMM dd, yyyy") doesn't work because you can't implicitly convert a string to date or something. That last example is exactly how I do it in the view.

How do I replicate that output in the JSON of an API controller?

NEW: The same seems true with decimals. I have prices that should include two decimals, but the JSON output in the controller only has as many as the user put in. This results in stuff like $20.5 followed by $0 and $22.55. The last of course being correct.

My price model looks like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Price Required!")]
        [Range(.00, Double.PositiveInfinity, ErrorMessage = "Must Be Positive Number!")]
        [Display(Name = "Price:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: Formatting and treating local time should be a UI concern where the UI (JavaScript or rendering engine) expects a standardized format (I.e. ISO Date format) which it converts, then ensures that any user input is converted back to that standardized format. Client-side formatting details won't be done server side in your model or domain entities unless you are storing and applying a per-client or per-region configuration within your application for formatting options. Decimal places, decimal symbols, currency symbol, date formats, etc. are all client formatting concerns.

Comment: @StevePy I just want my infinite scroller to display the right price former which is 2 decimal places. To do that it needs to be formatted before it is rendered in the JSON output in the api controller. I got the date working with a converter class, but trying to do the same with price seems to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
 public string StringDate  
 { 
     set => Date?.ToString("0:MM/dd/yyyy")
 }
```